# Finding the maximum value of a product given certain values for x,y and z

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization

Find the maximum value of $$(1-x)(2-y)(3-z)(x+\frac y2+\frac z3)$$ where $$x<1,y<2,z<3,x+\frac y2+\frac z3>0$$

I tried several cases to find a certain product. I tried 7 such cases. Three of them yield negative values while 4 gave postive fractional values. I chose the highest value which is 5/3. I already gave up and looked at the answer at the back of the questionnaire. The answer is $$\frac {243}{128}$$

Can anyone help me in answering this question?

Comment: I'm guessing by the tags that x,y, and z are integers, and not real numbers. Can you confirm this?

Comment: @Nick:  the stated answer seems to imply reals.

Comment: @RossMillikan: I only say because of the tag "number theory". Also, the tag "pre-calculus", where the obvious solution (at least what I would think to do naturally) would be to use calculus to do the maximization.

Comment: Do you mean the algebra-precalculus tag?  I would take partial derivatives with respect to $x,y,z$ and set them to zero.  Without that tool, I think you are reduced to trying to write your expression as a sum of squares.  That looks hard to me.

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to your solution: find where the gradient is zero. But if it's pre-calculus, that might not be helpful to the poster.

Comment: @Nick:  yes, I asked OP about that.  I wouldn't have much hope for the sum of squares approach, but the given answer, which is $\frac {3^5}{2^7},$ seems to indicate a maximum inside the region as opposed to on the boundary.

Comment: As much as possible, I need a solution without the use of calculus since this question came from an HS Math Olympiad Questionnaire and I do not think they allow calculus as a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By A.M-G.M, 
    \begin{align*}
 (1-x)(2-y)(3-z)\left(x+\frac{y}{2}+\frac{z}{3}\right)&= 6(1-x)\left(1-\frac{y}{2}\right)\left(1-\frac{z}{3}\right)\left(x+\frac{y}{2}+\frac{z}{3}\right)\\
 &\leq 6\left(\frac{1-x+1-\frac{y}{2}+1-\frac{z}{3}+x+\frac{y}{2}+\frac{z}{3}}{4}\right)^4 \\
 &= 6\frac{81}{256} = \frac{243}{128}
 \end{align*}

Comment: Very nice solution! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the partial derivative approach.  The partial of your expression with respect to $x$ is $(y-2)(z-3)(12x+3y+2z-6)$  The first two factors cannot be zero by your region requirement, so $12x+3y+2z=6$.  If you take the other two partials, you get three equations in three unknowns, with solution $x=\frac 14, y=\frac 12, z=\frac 34$ and the expression is duly $\frac {3^5}{2^7}$  If you don't have partials available, you will need to write the objective function as a sum of squares and the known optimal point will help.

Comment: As much as possible, I need a solution without the use of calculus since this question came from an HS Math Olympiad Questionnaire and I do not think they allow calculus as a solution.

Comment: How do I express this as a sum of squares?

Comment: I haven't done so and don't know that it can be.  You would expand out the expression and write it as $a(x-\frac14)^2+$ maybe $(x+y-\frac 34)^2$+ other terms.  The idea is you don't have to differentiate to find the minimum now-you just look at the expression.